# Why did Dio cut off his head and not regenerate his body?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In the first season of Jojo's Bizarre Adventure, when Dio falls off a cliff, he cuts off his own head.

1. Why?

At the end of the season, we see him in Jojo's wedding boat, his head in a container.

2. Why didn't he regenerate a body during all this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hamon was spreading throughout his body, and if he did not separate himself from his body, Dio Brando would die.
2. The Hamon that destroyed his body, probably prevented him from regenerating his body. Dio Brando in the final episode of Part 1 says something along the lines of "This is the man who brought me to my current state. Give him [Jonathan Joestar] a swift death." This alludes me to believe that it was because of JoJo's Hamon that Dio Brando is unable to regenerate his own body, and thus wants to take over JoJo's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because Dio Brando is a vampire that is allergic to Hamon. If Hamon successfully touches the vampire, then the vampire starts to burn due to Hamon reviving the vampire back to their human form, and then finally killing them.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Looks like this is a reply to [an existing answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/46243), instead of an attempt to answer the question: "Why did Dio cut off his own head? Why didn't he regenerate a body?" Compared to conventional forums, Stack Exchange is a Q&A site. "Answer" should be used to answer the question, not as a reply to other posts. Instead, you can comment/reply to another post after earning 50 reputation. Consider [edit]ing the answer to clarify the answer, then taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! how can I buy reputation?

Comment: You can't buy reputation, but you can earn it e.g. by getting upvotes from writing a good question/answer. Please consult the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for further info.

Comment: lol @SirPinkyJoJOo as long as you write questions and answers that are pretty good then getting reputation wont be a problem.

Comment: p2w for the rep kekw